# Catch RealmFileException

Tags: android, realm

A very small subset of users are getting this error:

> Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException Unable to open a
>   realm at path

I've done some searching and it looks like this is due to a corrupted realm file.  I've put in the below code to catch the error, delete the realm, and create a new one:

```
try {
  final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
  // realm opened successfully.  Do nothing
  realm.close();
} catch (RealmFileException e) { 
     // database corrupted. delete database
     Realm.deleteRealm(NbcRealmConfiguration.getInstance().getRealmConfiguration(getApplicationContext()));
     Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name(getString(R.string.database_name))
                    .schemaVersion(REALM_SCHEMA)
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build());
}
```

My Question:

I'm unable to replicate this issue so I can't test this fix.  **Does anyone know if this is the right way to do this or can you suggest a better way?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: do u have any logs ?

Comment: Are you doing any migration or simply initializing Realm?

Comment: Also, are you storing Realm DB in external storage or internal storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is the "right" way is up to you.  This will regen the Realm, but I am wondering how the realm became corrupted to begin with.

Assuming this is a problem in production I would likely go ahead with this to resolve the immediate issue.  I would add some logging so you can see when this is happening.  Then I would make it a priority to look further into the issue. Pay attention to when it is happening and at what rate. Look for trends or patterns that will help you identify the root cause. Look further up the stack to see if it is always coming from the same code.

If it is not in production, and is not interfering with other team members, then I would leave the issue as troubleshooting is easier when there is an active problem.

Comment: thank you for that.  We've only seen it effect 2 users out of over 300k but both of those user were on 4.4 and after next release, we're raising the min sdk to 5.0 so I wanted to put something in that would allow them continued use of the app post EOL